# TransformToAncestor doesn't always work

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I'm currently working on my first WPF app.
I'm getting data from some XML file and based on that file I populate stackpanel with some dynamically created buttons.

later on I need to retrieve X coordinate from specific button for which i use method:

```
private double GetStationCoordinates(int stationIdx)
    {
        foreach (Button station in StationMap.Children)
        {
            if (stationIdx != Convert.ToInt16(station.Tag)) continue;
            var relativePoint = station.TransformToAncestor(Application.Current.MainWindow).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
            //Console.WriteLine(stationIdx + " " + relativePoint.ToString());
            return relativePoint.X;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

And then I use this coordinates to paint some points in other panel under the buttons. It all worked fine until I set my main window property

```
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
```

Now - when I paint my points for the first time after launching the app (and after I populate StackPanel with buttons) they all (points) receive the same X coordinate - 11.
When i hit Refresh button everything is ok.But the first paint - just after adding buttons is problematic.
Same problem occurs when I reload buttons configuration xml file. I'm starting with clearing all the Children in StackPanel and populating it with new ones. After that first painting of points is broken - GetStationCoordinates returns 11 for every button.
Is it somehow connected to autosize property of main window?

Comment: When/Where are you calling `GetStationCoordinates` the first time?

Comment: the app flow is like this:
form loaded
load configuration data from xml file to my map object
update 3 labels with names, dates and comments from map object
build buttons in foreach statement from map object and add them to StackPanel
Create new object with points to paint collection
foreach point call for coordinates from button with matching Tag
paint that point and several other things - lines etc.

It seems that all this buttons maybe already in collection but not yet placed properly on stackpanel

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to get the position of elements that haven't been correctly positioned yet. Defer that code until the view has loaded, using any of these two approaches:

a) Subscribe to the `Loaded` event of the view and do it there.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Loaded -= Window_Loaded;  // Or else it could get called again later

    int id;
    // do stuff

    GetStationCoordinates(id);
}
```

b) Put it in an asynchronous call with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

```
private void SomeCode()
{
    int id;
    // do other stuff

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            GetStationCoordinates(id);
        }),
        DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
}
```

Comment: obviously my code is launched after window loaded and after all the buttons have been rendered.
Finally i choose some simple math calculations to get needed coordinates.

public static double GetStationCoordinates(int stationIdx)
        {
            return 11 + BtnSize*(stationIdx - FirstStationIdx);
        }